# Example III.3.2(1) of Baumslag's "Topics in Combinatorial Group Theory": proving $F=\operatorname{gp}(1+\xi\mid \xi\in\Xi)$ is free.

Tags: group-theory, power-series, noncommutative-algebra, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

This question is a little tricky (for me, at least), since in the textbook the proof of

> **Theorem 5:** Every subgroup of a free group is free.

is not yet provided (even though I've seen such proofs in Magnus *et al.*'s *"Combinatorial Group Theory [...],"* in Lyndon & Schupp's *"Combinatorial Group Theory,"* and in Johnson's *"Presentation$\color{red}{s}$ of Groups"*).

### Here is the exercise:

> Let $\Xi$ be a set of non-commuting variables. Consider the group of units of the ring of formal power series, with integer coefficients, in the non-commuting variables coming from $\Xi$. Prove that
>
> $$F=\operatorname{gp}(1+\xi\mid \xi\in\Xi)$$
>
> is free on $\{1+\xi\mid \xi\in\Xi\}$. (This is a theorem of W. Magnus.)

---

Before this exercise is the following

### Hint:

> Before starting out on the proof of Theorem 5, we give some examples of some groups which turn out to be free. *The proofs require the criterion (iv), of Theorem 1 of Chapter 1.* (Emphasis added.)

Okay, so here is that criterion:

> **Theorem 1:** (iv) Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $X$ generates $G$. If every reduced $X$-word is different from $1$, then $G$ is a free group, freely generated by $X$.
>
> **Notation:** Let $X\subseteq G$. The subgroup of $G$ generated by $X$ is denoted $\operatorname{gp}(X)$.

This notation is so that such subgroups are not confused with presentations.

---

*Thoughts:*

This is a question I think I should be able to do myself, especially since it seems to be a matter of letting $x_\xi:=1+\xi$ - or something to that effect - as there are no restrictions on the elements of $\Xi$. But then I suspect I'd be using Theorem 5, which would result in an annoying anachronism in my understanding of the material in the book.

Please help :)

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you want. Are you asking how to prove "the exercise" using Theorem 1?

Comment: Yes, @LeeMosher. I'm sorry it's unclear. Please let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: Writing an actual question somewhere, with a question mark, would help.

Comment: Is that any better, @LeeMosher?

Comment: There's still no question mark, but clear enough from the comments, I suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand it, your job is to apply Theorem 1, not Theorem 5.

So to start, you should take a sequence of elements $\xi_1,...,\xi_n \in \Xi$ and a sequence of exponents $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n \in \{-1,+1\}$, and you should assume that for all $i=1,...,n-1$ if $\xi_i = \xi_{i+1}$ then $\epsilon_i = \epsilon_{i+1}$. Using those assumptions, your job is then to prove that product
$$(1 + \xi_1)^{\epsilon_1}\cdots(1 + \xi_n)^{\epsilon_n}  \quad (*)
$$
is not the identity element of the ring of formal power series. The assumptions were made in order to express that the product $(*)$ is a reduced word in the set of generators $X = \{1 + \xi \mid \xi \in \Xi\}$.

Can you take it from here?